# Error Code 1900.5.999 on Apple Device

Tags: simcity-buildit

Every time I log in to Simcity-buildit on my iPad I get the following error repeatedly,

```
Hello Mayor!
There was an error processing your store transaction.
(Error code: 1900.5.999 - Player id: #######)
```

Answer (score 1):

EA support said that they are working on a fix in a future update, but for now you can either,

1. Keep closing the error message until it stops coming back.
2. Enable in-app purchases for the game.